# R: Error when grouping data using subset or index methods- produces list of all column names

Tags: r, indexing, syntax-error, subset

I am encountering an error when trying to group my data based on categories of a variable and I am not sure why it is happening because I have used the two most widely recommended methods, `subset(dataframe, variable==X)` and `dataframe[dataframe4variable ==X]`, successfully with past data sets and just now using the mtcars dataset.

The problem is that when I try to run my code, I get an error in which R just prints out the names of all of my variables(see below).

I am not quite sure how to "show" this problem-- any recommendations regarding what information would be useful to you all would be greatly appreciated. This problem is not reproducible with other datasets. Thank you for any advice you are able to give.

My dataset "wits" has 363 observations and 92 variables. My variable "complete" is a factor variable with four levels: "completed all", "stopped after demos", "stopped after consent", and "skipped manip bc poor id." I would like to create a new dataset made up only of participants with "completed all". I have tried these two methods:

```
wits_c <- wits[wits$complete=="Completed all", ]
wits_c <-subset(wits,complete=="Completed all")
```

Which results in the following error:

```
Error: Columns `Start`, `End`, `GameCode`, `workerID`, `condition`,   `about`, `valid`, `consv`, `merit1`, `merit2`, `merit3`, `gender`, `gender_TEXT`, `poorid`, `choseskip`, `age`, `edu`, `race`, `race_TEXT`, `complete`, `distracted`, `happen`, `about__1`, `playread`, `thinking_1`, `thinking_2`, `thinking_3`, `thinking_4`, `thinking_5`, `thinking_6`, `thinking_7`, `text`, `logical_1`, `logical_2`, `logical_3`, `logical_4`, `controll_1`, `controll_2`, `controll_3`, `controll_4`, `controll_5`, `controll_6`, `controll_7`, `controll_8`, `controll_9`, `controll_10`, `privatesol`, `publicsol`, `privatesol_2`, `privatesol_3`, `privatesol_5`, `publicsol_2`, `publicsol_3`, `publicsol_5`, `policy_1`, `policy_2`, `policy_3`, `policy_4`, `colaction_5`, `colaction_6`, `colaction_7`, `colaction_8`, `colaction_10`, `colaction_13`, `joke`, `random`, `say`, `wits`, `wits_nb`, `neutral`, `rural_id`, `relig_id`, `prog_id`, `vignette`, `merit3R`, `policy_3R`, `policy_4R`, `controll_4R`, `controll_5R`,`co
```

Thank you to user Markdly for the suggestion to include the following output which provides more detailed information about my dataset:

```
dput(head(wits))
structure(list(Start = structure(c(1499525516, 1499516293, 1499516379, 
1499516319, 1499516949, 1499516709), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), End = structure(c(1499525762, 1499518121, 
1499516954, 1499517222, 1499517412, 1499517512), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), GameCode = c(2991999, 5712506, 1002944, 
8916111, 3495462, 9127270), workerID = c("ACIHCWKHNFC7U", "A3UAO2LYUPO7L6", 
"A8L94A9EF23BV", "A258JTYUD56LOE", "A12SJSJIUR3A23", "A1HHOCO3ZZHCJZ"
), condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("WITS", 
"WITS No Blurb", "Neutral", "Read"), class = "factor"), about = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2), valid = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = 
c("valid responses", 
"invalid responses"), class = "factor"), consv = c(4, 2, 2, 6, 
4, 4), merit1 = c(5, 3, 2, 4, 6, 4), merit2 = c(4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 
4), merit3 = c(3, 4, 2, 5, 4, 5), gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("man", "woman", "non-binary", "other"
), class = "factor"), gender_TEXT = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
poorid = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("not id as poor", 
"id as poor"), class = "factor"), choseskip = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), .Label = c("poor but continued", "poor and skipped"), class = "factor"), 
age = c(28, 30, 33, 41, 26, 30), edu = c(5, 5, 6, 5, 3, 5
), race = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("white", 
"black", "latino", "asian", "native american", "other", "multiracial"
), class = "factor"), race_TEXT = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), complete = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Completed 
all", 
"Stopped after demos", "Stopped after consent", "Skipped manip bc poor id"
), class = "factor"), distracted = c(4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5), happen = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), about__1 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), playread = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), thinking_1 = c(1, 6, 5, 4, 6, 4), thinking_2 = c(4, 
3, 5, 1, 5, 5), thinking_3 = c(1, 4, 7, 4, 5, 5), thinking_4 = c(6, 
4, 7, 1, 5, 3), thinking_5 = c(5, 3, 6, 6, 5, 4), thinking_6 = c(4, 
3, 7, 6, 6, 4), thinking_7 = c(6, 3, 7, 6, 5, 5), text = c(2, 
4, 5, 4, 2, 3), logical_1 = c(1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), logical_2 = c(2, 
4, 3, 4, 5, 4), logical_3 = c(4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4), logical_4 = c(1, 
6, 3, 4, 4, 3), controll_1 = c(6, 6, 1, 4, 4, 4), controll_2 = c(1, 
3, 1, 4, 5, 5), controll_3 = c(1, 4, 3, 6, 4, 5), controll_4 = c(3, 
4, 6, 3, 4, 4), controll_5 = c(6, 3, 6, 1, 4, 4), controll_6 = c(3, 
3, 1, 3, 5, 4), controll_7 = c(2, 5, 1, 5, 4, 5), controll_8 = c(2, 
2, 1, 4, 5, 3), controll_9 = c(6, 2, 6, 3, 5, 5), controll_10 = c(1, 
3, 6, 2, 5, 3), privatesol = c(5, 5.33333333333333, 12, 8, 
8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333), publicsol = c(7.66666666666667, 
2.66666666666667, 12, 2, 11.3333333333333, 8.33333333333333
), privatesol_2 = c(1, 11, 12, 11, 11, 3), privatesol_3 = c(3, 
2, 12, 2, 3, 11), privatesol_5 = c(11, 3, 12, 11, 11, 11), 
publicsol_2 = c(11, 3, 12, 2, 12, 11), publicsol_3 = c(11, 
2, 12, 2, 11, 3), publicsol_5 = c(1, 3, 12, 2, 11, 11), policy_1 = c(1, 
5, 6, 1, 4, 4), policy_2 = c(3, 2, 6, 1, 5, 4), policy_3 = c(1, 
3, 2, 6, 5, 3), policy_4 = c(6, 3, 5, 6, 5, 4), colaction_5 = c(2, 
5, 6, 1, 2, 5), colaction_6 = c(6, 4, 1, 6, 5, 4), colaction_7 = c(6, 
2, 6, 1, 3, 4), colaction_8 = c(4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4), colaction_10 = c(4, 
3, 1, 6, 5, 4), colaction_13 = c(3, 2, 6, 1, 2, 3), joke = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2), random = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), say = c(NA, 
"Nope", NA, "This was  highly  biased survey.", "good survey", 
"NO"), wits = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), wits_nb = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), neutral = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), rural_id = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0), relig_id = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), prog_id = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1), vignette = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("WITS", "WITS No Blurb", "Neutral", "Read"
), class = "factor"), merit3R = c(4, 3, 5, 2, 3, 2), policy_3R = c(6, 
4, 5, 1, 2, 4), policy_4R = c(1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3), controll_4R = c(4, 
3, 1, 4, 3, 3), controll_5R = c(1, 4, 1, 6, 3, 3), controll_9R = c(1, 
5, 1, 4, 2, 2), controll_10R = c(6, 4, 1, 5, 2, 4), colaction_6R = c(1, 
3, 6, 1, 2, 3), colaction_10R = c(3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 3), logical = c(2, 
4, 3.75, 4, 4.5, 3.75), cognition = structure(c(1, 6, 5, 
4, 6, 4, 4, 3, 5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 4, 7, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 7, 1, 
5, 3, 5, 3, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 7, 6, 6, 4, 6, 3, 7, 6, 5, 
5), .Dim = 6:7), engage = c(5, 3, 6.66666666666667, 6, 5.33333333333333, 
4.33333333333333), pertake = c(3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 
6.33333333333333, 2, 5, 4.33333333333333), policy = c(2.75, 
3.75, 4.75, 1, 3.25, 3.75), colaction = c(3.16666666666667, 
3.5, 6, 1, 2.16666666666667, 3.66666666666667), controllability = c(2.7, 
3.9, 1.2, 4.5, 3.7, 3.8), completebi = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Completed all", "Stopped after demos"
), class = "factor"), gender2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("man", "woman"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Start", "End", "GameCode", "workerID", "condition", "about", "valid", 
"consv", "merit1", "merit2", "merit3", "gender", "gender_TEXT", 
"poorid", "choseskip", "age", "edu", "race", "race_TEXT", "complete", 
"distracted", "happen", "about__1", "playread", "thinking_1", 
"thinking_2", "thinking_3", "thinking_4", "thinking_5", "thinking_6", 
"thinking_7", "text", "logical_1", "logical_2", "logical_3", 
"logical_4", "controll_1", "controll_2", "controll_3", "controll_4", 
"controll_5", "controll_6", "controll_7", "controll_8", "controll_9", 
"controll_10", "privatesol", "publicsol", "privatesol_2", "privatesol_3", 
"privatesol_5", "publicsol_2", "publicsol_3", "publicsol_5", 
"policy_1", "policy_2", "policy_3", "policy_4", "colaction_5", 
"colaction_6", "colaction_7", "colaction_8", "colaction_10", 
"colaction_13", "joke", "random", "say", "wits", "wits_nb", "neutral", 
"rural_id", "relig_id", "prog_id", "vignette", "merit3R", "policy_3R", 
"policy_4R", "controll_4R", "controll_5R", "controll_9R", "controll_10R", 
"colaction_6R", "colaction_10R", "logical", "cognition", "engage", 
"pertake", "policy", "colaction", "controllability", "completebi", 
"gender2"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Editing your question to include the results of `dput(head(wits))` will most likely be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wits$complete
#[1] Completed \nall Completed \nall Completed \nall Completed \nall Completed \nall Completed \nall
#Levels: Completed \nall Stopped after demos Stopped after consent Skipped manip bc poor id
```

You can see it's "Completed \nall" not "Completed all" in your wits data frame.

```
##So, you just use which function to subset your wits data frame.
which(wits$complete == "Completed \nall")
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6   ## This is index of the row. You put this to subet you data frame as below and you are good to go.

## So, this will subset your data frame
wits[which(wits$complete == "Completed \nall"),]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for working on this! I tried the code you suggested and it produced a dataset with zero observations, but when  I redid it, still using which(), it worked perfectly. So I guess my data doesn't like subset()? Also it is not turning things into code when I use the quotes around them like 'this.' Sorry